# Three20 - open url for a shared view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, three20

I know that if map a url with `from:toViewController:`, then open that url will create a new view controller and if `from:toSharedViewController` is used then a shared instance will be used.

But for example

```
 [map from:@"tt://tabbar/(initWithString:)" toSharedViewController:[MyTabbarController class]];
 TTOpenURL(@"tt://tabbar/string");
```

This will invoke something similar to

```
 [[MyTabbarController alloc] initWithString:@"string"]
```

But what will be happened if `TTOpenURL(@"tt://tabbar/somethingelse")` in called later?
Since a shared object is used so will the `initWithString:` be called twice on a same instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is : no. I.e., init will not be called on an already initialized instance, but a new instance will be allocated and initialized.

This is due to Three20 associating the object to its full URL, which in your case is either "tt://tabbar/string" or "tt://tabbar/somethingelse", so that when querying the `TTURLMap`, no already existing object will be found and a new one will be instantiated. At least, this is true as of Three20 1.0.3. But I guess they have not changed this.

In my opinion, the shared controller mechanism is to be used in very specific cases, like for a setting view, and it should not be thought as a sort of Three20-implemented singleton. Each time I tried to rely on this for more "clever" usage of the TTURLMap, I found myself going back to a non shared controller.

Comment: Is possible to open a same instance and call a setter such as `setString:` not `initWithString:`? Otherwise it is almost not possible to reuse a controller. I found `from:toViewController:selector` but I am not sure how to use it

Comment: You can do that. Instead of calling `TTOpenURL`, you can also use `[[TTNavigator navigator] viewControllerForURL:@"xxxx"]` if you just want to get the existing controller.